# Cannot open form in child from parent component - 'cannot read property xxx'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Scenario: I have a list of **companies** that each have an array of **projects** as one of their variables. I will display the list of companies in the parent component/html, and only when clicking on their corresponding 'open' does a child component open to display the list of projects for that company. This list is a FormArray that is editable.

I created this [**FormArray**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-example-amh) example as the standalone **projects** component to interact and perform CRUD operations with example data.

My goal now is to open the form as a child component when I click the 'open' button on each individual company as in **[THIS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-form-as-child)** stackblitz.

In the example it appears that `this.setData();` within the constructor is causing the upset.

I have found through experimentation that, by commenting this line out causes the app not to crash, but of course the FormArray will not be loaded when I click the company 'open' button. However, I have also found that writing `{{company.name}}` in the child component **DOES** output the company details in the child, so it shows data is going through correctly.

I just cannot understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Should I refer the last stackblitz example to work on?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes please :-)

Comment: Are familiar with shared service?

Comment: I can provide you a solution with shared service if you are ok with that then!

Comment: Any solution would be great :-)

Comment: Have added an answer, check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ngDoCheck() lifecyle hook

> A lifecycle hook that invokes a custom change-detection function for a
>   directive, in addition to the check performed by the default
>   change-detector.

```
ngDoCheck() {

  this.setData();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `this.setData()` call inside `SubForm` class constructor.

You never checked for null/undefined data. So, initially when the component loads, `this.company` is undefined. Hence, `name` variable will be assigned `undefined` value.

So, when program tries to access the value of `this.company` in the below line, it gives error:

```
setData() {
  let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.data;
  control.push(this.fb.group({
    name: this.company.name,
    ...
  }));
}
```

---

### Solution:

Add null/undefined check for `this.company` before calling `this.setData()`:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.array([])
    })
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.company)){
      this.setData();
    }
    console.log(this.company)
}
```

Comment: This indeed stops the warning messages, but when I click the Company to display the project data, it is blank. Could it be that I am trying to access my data incorrectly?

Comment: @physicsboy Because `constructor` is only called once before `ngOnInit`. So, it is not a good place to have this logic. Refer: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

As I tried on the StackBlitz, few changes to be done to get it working:

You have to access the `@Input` variable in `ngOnInit()` by implementing an `OnInit` interface.

Parent Component .TS file:

```
isOpened : boolean = false;  // one local variable of type boolean to open child compo

openInfo(company) {
    this.isOpened = !this.isOpened;
    this.openCompany = company;
    this.open=true;
}
```

Parent Component HTML Code:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let data of DATA">
    {{data.name}}
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openInfo(data)">open</button>
</mat-card>
<div *ngIf="isOpened">
  <subform [company]="openCompany"></subform>
</div>
```

Child Component .TS Code:

Import this:

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, Input
} from '@angular/core';
```

and Component class:

```
export class SubForm implements OnInit {

@Input() company: any;
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.array([])
   })
   console.log(this.company);
   this.setData();
  }
}
```

[A working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-form-as-child-forjfz)